# Запись в новый файл с добавлением цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Здравствуйте,

Столкнулся с проблемой записи данных в логи. Каждые новые данные, переданные через сокет, нужно записать в отдельный файл с новым названием (log1.txt, log2.txt….)

Есть мысль, что нужно проверять директорию на файлы, считывать имя в строку и добавлять цифру. Может у кого-нибудь есть совет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имена файлов(log1.txt, log2.txt...) принципиальны? Если нет, то по моему проще всего файлы логов именовать по дате-времени создания (что-то вроде YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.txt). Но это опять же если не чаще раз в секунду пишутся файлы

Comment: Большое спасибо,

Не сразу подумал, что можно дату записывать